# Countdown end case resulting in Javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple countdown plugin which counts down second by second to a time, and upon reaching that time it runs a callback function of my choosing.

What I have discovered today is that if I have two countdowns on the same page, and one countdown finishes, a javascript error occurs because a variable becomes undefined, which also breaks the second countdown.

Here's the code:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.countdown = function(options, callback) {
    var $self = $(this);

    var settings = {
        'date' : null,
    }

    if(options) {
        $.extend(settings, options);
    }

    function countdownProcessor() {
        var eventDate = Date.parse(settings.date) / 1000;
        var currentDate = Math.floor($.now() / 1000);

        if (eventDate <= currentDate) {
            callback.call(this);
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

        var secondsBetween = eventDate - currentDate;

        // processing logic here.

    }

    countdownProcessor();
    interval = setInterval(countdownProcessor, 1000);
}

})(jQuery);
```

The issue is with the if statement which checks to make sure the date has not already occurred:

```
if (eventDate <= currentDate) {
    callback.call(this);
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

When this condition becomes true, the callback completes successfully, but `clearInterval` does not because the variable `interval` is not defined - this is because the countdown function is run before interval is declared.

I've tried fixing it by switching the interval variable declaration and `countdownProcessor();` around, but this doesn't help because it simply causes the first, ended countdown to count into the negatives.

I've a few other methods like changing the scope and order of declaration of some of the code, but it invariably leads to the countdown either **A)** counting into the negatives, or **B)** still erroring out.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `var`:

```
var interval = setInterval(countdownProcessor,1000);
```

This makes the `interval` local to each countdown that is being run, rather than global to the entire page.